# Replacing UIViewController with UITabBarController in iOS 7 Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

this is what i have in my storyboard:

[image]

The View with the tree in it is a UIViewController. It has a class called BKFirstViewController.
Now what i want to do is have the user type in his login data. Then the server validates the login data and when i get a positive response from the server i want to replace the green UIViewController with a UITabBarController.

So what i did is, i created a UITabBarController in Main.Storyboard and i gave it the storyboard identifyer: "logedInView"
Then i gave all three of them a controller named: BKLogedInController
This controller i created manually since xCode doesn't do it for me

Next i googled how to switch between ViewControllers and voila Stackoverflow popped up:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    UITabBarController *logedInCtrl = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "logedInView"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:logedInCtrl animated:YES];
```

My problem is: nothing happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how Im currently doing it the same thing on ios7. In your photos it seems your using a navigation controller not a tabbarcontroller.

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController * vc = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"start"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Be sure to give your storyboard an I.D

[image]

Answer (score -2):

First, you should stop googling and read Apple's documentation, particularly the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS". If you had, you would know that you can't push a view controller unless it's embedded in a navigation controller. So, in your case, self.navigationController will be nil, and that line will do nothing. What you want to do is switch the window's root view controller:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = logedInCtrl;
```